# Can a book be an active voice?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, subjects, active-voice

Original sentence in a passive voice:

> In this book, the system for mind training of short exercises was developed.

Is this sentence legal? (Can a book develop?)

> **This book developed** the system for mind training of short exercises.

You may suggest other options without use of the words "I/We".

Comment: Of course it can, but your question isn't really valid since that sentence doesn't indicate that "book" performs the action of the verb "develop." To do that, it would have to say something like, "The system for mind training of short exercises was developed *by* this book." The prepositional phrase "*in* this book" denotes that the action of the verb "develop" was performed in it but does ***not*** denote that it was the book that performed it any more than saying, "In the house, a system was developed," indicates the house developed the system, only that some unnamed subject did.

Comment: Understand that when speaking about a book it’s not that the book is doing the developing. This is an idiomatic way of saying that the writing within the book sets out, develops, etc the ideas. It is much better to speak of the author developing the ideas in his/her book, though as others have suggested below.

Comment: This sentence doesn't make sense. The *author* developed the system, or the book *triggered the development of* the system, or the book *presented* the system.

Comment: Are you asking in general whether an inanimate object can be the subject of an active verb, or are you asking whether this particular sentence is correct?

Comment: @gotube, I am asking about a book summary, that may contain at least 6 sentences as: 1) The book develops 2) The book shows 3) The book obtains 4) The book discovers etc..

Comment: @Ben I'd edit the question to ask what you're really asking if you want a satisfying answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you *mean* is "Can a book be the subject of an active verb?"

You can certainly say *This book tells/shows/relates/explains something*.

I see no reason why you cannot equally say *This book develops a system ...*

*Developed* would be odd, unless there was a specific reason to refer to the book in the past - eg as part of a historical sketch of the development of a system.

(*The system for mind training of short exercises* means nothing to me, and I would suspect it of being a clumsy translation from another language. I suspect it should read *a system of short exercises for mind training*.)

Comment: I would rather say that something in a written work such as a logical argument, a scheme of some sort, a complex hypothesis, a method, etc, was developed by the author/the author developed it. In _Philosophiae Naturalis Principia Mathematica_, Isaac Newton laid out (developed) his laws of motion, law of universal gravitation and an extension of Kepler’s laws of planetary motion. You could say the _Principia_ developed those ideas, but I would avoid such a construction.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, can you please write better options for the sentence?

Comment: Yes, it's a bit strained, but I think it works as a shorthand for _the book lays out the development of_.

Comment: And the iWeb corpus has 181 hits for "book develops".  Not all of them have this structure, but there are e.g. " the book develops the basic ideas of the theory of relativity", " the book develops an entire alternate paradigm of career planning", and "This book develops an original theory of group and organizational behavior."

Comment: @ColinFine, can you please supply the official reference for your answer?

Comment: @Ben, there is no such thing as "the official reference" for anything in English.